# TokenMismatchException when post to a laravel application externally

Tags: php, laravel

So I have an application that sends an AJAX request to an external server which does some stuff then makes a post call to the laravel application that made the initial call.

So I am trying to do a POST call to the laravel application. Now from the AJAX request i am sending the `csrf_token()`

Here are the headers I've put into my post request:

```
X-CSRF-TOKEN: LO8Dg7j1jZssXXGSLIa8inBgh2Y1QSsp6Birc1Ui
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

That token belongs to the logged in user that made the AJAX request. Now the problem i'm getting is from this i get a `TokenMismatchException`500 error.

Is there something else I need to do in my external post calls headers in order to not encounter this error?

As i've got the CSRF token i am using a rest client to try send a test post using those headers and I get the same error?

The aim is on the recieving laravel app controller will then be able to use the token and i'll be able to use `$request->user();` to get the user.

Note the recieving route has the `web` middleware attached to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are making request from another server external url.Because of this you are getting erorr.Csrf token works with the same application not working if you try to exicute from other application. so you can disable csrf token.

if you want to disable token for all request then  add this in VerifyCsrfToken

```
  protected $except = [
            '/*',
        ];
```

**Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection**

Sometimes you may wish to exclude a set of URIs from CSRF protection. For example, if you are using Stripe to process payments and are utilizing their webhook system, you will need to exclude your Stripe webhook handler route from CSRF protection since Stripe will not know what CSRF token to send to your routes.

Typically, you should place these kinds of routes outside of the web middleware group that the  RouteServiceProvider applies to all routes in the routes/web.php file. However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
    ];
}
```

Ref:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Comment: Okay great! How can I take the token and get the user it belongs to in order to authenticate who it was?

Comment: if you are accing laravel from exteranal apps then you can use jwt token or you have ot disable token as i said in the answer.laravel authenticate based on session not on token.if you need token based authentication then you have to use jwt  any other option l

Comment: As the connection would only be used from one particular server to mine could I just bind a token to a user when I create it or send the user Id through the request headers?

Comment: it will not accept csrf token from other server it will throw token mismatch exception

Comment: Sorry let me be more clear seems as it starts on my app and the request ends up on it at some point could when I send the request out to my API I send a Auth token which would a random string bound to a user record on the database. I then have it in the header when it calls back to the app at the later point to go get the user?

Comment: you can read this rticle https://ponyfoo.com/articles/json-web-tokens-vs-session-cookies